# If a theory is decidable in the existential fragment, does this mean that there is a (terminating) method to obtain witnesses of satisfaction?

Tags: z3, smt, quantifiers, first-order-logic

I am concerned with whether there are algorithms (e.g., implemented in SMT solvers) that guarantee termination on the task of giving models of existential formulae; in the same way they guarantee termination for the satisfiability problem. Let me try to explain myself.

---

If a first-order theory `T` is decidable on its existential fragment, this means that there is a method (that guarantees termination) that solves the satisfiability problem for all existential formulae of `T`. Am I right?

My question is: does `T` being existential-decidable imply that we have a method (that guarantees termination) to obtain models of existential formulae within `T`? In other words, if we have a method to solve satisfiability on existential formulae of `T`, does this mean we also have a method to obtain models of such formulae (in satisfiable instances)?

For instance, consider the theory of linear integer arithmetic. We know there is a terminating algorithm (i.e., Cooper's method) that performs quantifier elimination (QE) yielding a decision procedure if all variables are bounded by the quantifiers. This means that Cooper can solve the satisfiability problem of linear arithmetic with a termination guarantee. And this also means that, if an SMT solver (say, Z3) implements Cooper for the satisfiability problem, then it (in theory) offers termination. Right?

However, what if we want to ask for a model? It is clear that, for this theory, it has not been necessary to compute a witness of satisfaction (it has been done using QE), so maybe there is no method to get this witness. In other words, we can e.g., decide satisfiability of `∃x,y. (x<y)` using Cooper, but not get a witness!

**So, is there a similar method that guarantees termination and offers a model?** Maybe some modification of QE methods? I think it could be the case, because QE methods somehow compute test-points and maybe we can extract witnesses of such points...

Also, consider finite theories (e.g., naturals up to `100`). Then, it is clear that, by enumeration, we can both have a method to decide satisfiability and return a witness. My concern is with respect to infinite theories. As we saw, QE does not imply witness obtention, but maybe there is some result out there that guarantees that if a theory is shown to be decidable with a QE method, then there is another method that computes witnesses.

In case of positive answer, do SMT solvers (any of them) implement these guarantee model-provision? If not, why is this so? Is there any information about this in the literature of SMT solvers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're asking if there are any scenarios where the SMT solver can say "yes this is SAT," but is unable to display a model for it.

This, by construction, doesn't happen in the typical DPLL(T) based SMT solving. The way such solvers work is by always finding a model in case of SAT. This does *not* mean that you can have some other algorithm to determine if something is SAT, but not be able to come up with a model. That's entirely possible in general theorem proving, but does not happen in what we usually consider under the purview of SMT solving. (Example from theorem proving: In a logic without excluded middle, you can establish something is false, yet not be able to show an instance. This is where the axiom-of-choice comes into play. But such techniques are way outside the realm of usual SMT solving.)

In the context of SMT solving, what we care about (usually) is finite-model finding. That is, can we demonstrate a small model? (This is very important in practice, as models are usually counter-examples, and the smaller the counter-example, the better.) If the model can only be infinite, you'll find that the SMT solvers usually won't terminate. There's a lot of research on this topic. This is a good paper to read: [http://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/~ajreynol/cav13.pdf](http://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/%7Eajreynol/cav13.pdf)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. I read the paper and some related ones; but I do not understand why DPLL(T) guarantees providing a model. It is my fault, since I do not understand many phrases in "3.3. A Finite Model Finding Strategy"  of the paper you suggested.

Comment: So I wonder if you can explain this easier example to me: consider pg. 38 in this "tutorial" (https://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/~ajreynol/pres-dpllt15.pdf), where the result is "LIA-unsatisfiable". I understood the "mapping" procedure with which we solve SMT formulae using SAT solving plus invocations on theory solvers. So the DPLL(T) architecture (pg 39) is an interplay between SAT and the theory solver. Then, in pg 41 it says: "M is T-satisfiable, return model, e.g. { x -> 2, y -> 3 … }". But how?! I mean, I still have the same doubt: how does the "theory solver" provide the model in T?

Comment: I mean, I do understand why DPLL(T) responds "sat/unsat", but it relies on theory solvers that may be capable to answer satisfiability yet not be able to provide the model. What does DPLL(T) add upon these solvers so that it can provide models? What am I missing?

Comment: The theory solver is responsible for answering if a conjunction of theory terms are satisfiable together. For instance, if you have a LIA solver, you ask: is the set '{x>y, x+1<y}' satisfiable. (Note that this set is always a conjunction of simple terms in that particular logic.) The LIA solvers job is to say "yes" or "no". In this case it'll say no, so the sat solver will kill that branch, and will try a different set based on the skeleton results it has. If it ran out of all options, it'll declare unsat.

Comment: If you're asking how the LIA solver answers UNSAT (or SAT if that's the case), that's the whole point of the DPLL(T) story: The theory solvers are designed to be able to deal with terms that involve a specific logic. They can deploy any number of algorithms. But bottom line, if they say "SAT", they are required to provide a model for demonstrating that satisfiability.

Comment: I just wonder how DPLL(T) instantiates variables in order to provide those models. I have to research more. Thanks again!

Comment: The main techniques are lazy- and eager- approaches. Here's a nice slide-deck to skim-through: https://ths.rwth-aachen.de/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/teaching/vorlesung_satchecking/ws14_15/04a_equality_handout.pdf

Comment: Thanks a lot, so it seems that I need to better study E-graphs and similars!